# Reading numbers, alphabets and special characters from text file one character at a time in c#

Tags: c#, file-io, special-characters

Everything works fine except that it doesn't read special characters.
My file "a.text" contains the following:

"ANBOCPDQERFSGTHUIVJWKXLYMZNAOBPCQDRESFTGUHVIWJXKYLZManbocpdqerfsgthuivjwkxlymznaobpcqdresftguhviwjxkylzm05162738495061728394<:>;(,).[?]`{'}"/~\!|@_#+$-%*^=&:<;>,(.)?[`]'{"}~/!\@|#_$+%-^*&="

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication12
{
    class Tester
    {              
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {             
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"d:\a.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            string s = "aDFn3&5(09@Df0!/";
            string c1 = "";
            string c2 = "";
            string c3 = "";
            byte[] text2 = new byte[1];
            byte[] text1;
            int i,j,k=0;
            while (k<16)
            {
                c1 = s.Substring(k, 1);
                if (Regex.IsMatch(c1, @"^[A-Z]+$"))
                {
                    i = 26;
                    j = 6;
                    fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                }
                else if (Regex.IsMatch(c1, @"^[a-z]+$"))
                {
                    i = 26;
                    j = 6;
                    fs.Seek(182, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                }
                else if (Regex.IsMatch(c1, @"^[0-9]+$"))
                {
                    i = 10;
                    j = 10;
                    fs.Seek(364, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                }
                else
                {
                    i = 32;
                    j = 10;
                    fs.Seek(-352, SeekOrigin.End);
                }
                while(i>0)
                {
                    fs.Read(text2, 0, 1);
                    c2 = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(text2);                      
                    if (c1 == c2)
                    {
                        Console.Write(c2);
                        break;
                    }
                    fs.Seek(j, SeekOrigin.Current);
                    i--;   
                }
                text1 = new byte[j];
                fs.Read(text1, 0, j);
                c3 = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(text1);
                Console.Write(c3);                
                Console.WriteLine();  
                k++;
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

I get blank spaces in between in my output where I am trying to read special characters and compare.
My guess the encoding for input c2 string is the problem, but I have tried all encoding type, UTF8, UNICODE, UTF7, UTF32 just to see anything helps.
Help me with this, all reply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get what you're trying to achieve or why you'd want to read a single character at a time.

If the file isn't too big, I'd read the whole file and then work with the string.

Something like:

```
private static void parseFile(string fileName)
{
    string content = File.ReadAllText(fileName, Encoding.UTF8);
    foreach (char character in content)
    {
        if (character >= 'A' && character <= 'Z')
        {
            // handle A-Z
        }
        else if (character >= 'a' && character <= 'z')
        {
            // handle a-z
        }
        else if (character >= '0' && character <= '9')
        {
            // handle 0-9
        }
        else
        {
            // handle everything else
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: also don't mix byte and char. And read about [Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: I am sorry my mistake, this is the content of my file:"A000000B000010C000100D000110E001000F001010G001100H001110I010000J010010K010100L010110M011000N000001O000011P000101Q000111R001001S001011T001101U001111V010001W010011X010101Y010111Z011001a100000b100010c100100d100110e101000f101010g101100h101110i110000j110010k110100l110110m111000n100001o100011p100101q100111r101001s101011t101101u101111v110001w110011x110101y110111z11100101110110000111101100012111011001031110110011411101101005111011010161110110110711101101118111011100091110111001, similarly for special characters I have given binary numbers.

Comment: I am getting a string as input in string 's', then then for each char in string say a number, an alphabet or special character I am replacing with binary numbers and storing it in second string. I am trying to encrypt the data in binary numbers. Later for decryption I ll use the similar file for replacing binary numbers with characters.

Comment: My code replaces everything except special characters, it doesn't read them at all and skips the loop and reads the next character in string thereby leaving a blank gap for the binary numbers of special character in the output.

Comment: Yes but reading the file as a whole to a string helped, no issue of encoding as comparison is done string values.

Comment: Glad to have been of any help. Still not exactly getting what you do, but maybe this will help you, too: interpret char as byte: `byte b = (byte)c;`, get string representation of bits in byte: `string bStr = Convert.ToString(b, 2);`, get back byte from string: `byte b2 = Convert.ToByte(bStr, 2);` and again interpret that as char: `char c2 = (char)b2;`
But again, be aware of the many traps you can fall in when working with encodings in any way shape or form!